# HttpSecurity, WebSecurity and AuthenticationManagerBuilder

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

Could anyone explain when to override `configure(HttpSecurity)`, `configure(WebSecurity)` and `configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder)`?

Answer (score 139):

**configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder)** is used to establish an authentication mechanism by allowing AuthenticationProviders to be added easily: e.g. The following defines the in-memory authentication with the in-built 'user' and 'admin' logins.

```
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
    auth
        .inMemoryAuthentication()
        .withUser("user")
        .password("password")
        .roles("USER")
    .and()
        .withUser("admin")
        .password("password")
        .roles("ADMIN","USER");
}
```

**configure(HttpSecurity)** allows configuration of web based security at a resource level, based on a selection match - e.g. The example below restricts the URLs that start with /admin/ to users that have ADMIN role, and declares that any other URLs need to be successfully authenticated.

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
}
```

**configure(WebSecurity)** is used for configuration settings that impact global security (ignore resources, set debug mode, reject requests by implementing a custom firewall definition). For example, the following method would cause any request that starts with /resources/ to be ignored for authentication purposes.

```
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web
        .ignoring()
        .antMatchers("/resources/**");
}
```

You can refer to the following link for more information [Spring Security Java Config Preview: Web Security](http://spring.io/blog/2013/07/03/spring-security-java-config-preview-web-security/)

Comment: Nice answer Nick. With spring-security-config-5.0.3 (which comes with spring-boot 2.0.0), I couldn't find the method `http.authorizeUrls()`, maybe it got renamed to `http.authorizeRequests()` some while ago.

Comment: I know this is old, but what's the best practice here? I have found examples of configure(HttpSecurity http) method implementations invoking http.antMatchers("/foo").permitAll()" which seems equivalent to invoking web.ignoring().antMatchers("/foo") in the configure(WebSecurity web) method.

Comment: great answer. I am wondering if we ever need to call permitAll on HttpSecurity? Can't we just ignore all open url's like /register or /login using WebSecurity? Then why does all tutorials or answers use HttpSecurity.permitAll for /register and /login but WebSecurity.ingore for /publics of /resources ? –

Answer (score 5):

General use of WebSecurity `ignoring()` method *omits Spring Security* and none of Spring Security’s features will be available.
WebSecurity is based above HttpSecurity.

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web
        .ignoring()
        .antMatchers("/resources/**")
        .antMatchers("/publics/**");
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
        .antMatchers("/publics/**").hasRole("USER") // no effect
        .anyRequest().authenticated();
}
```

WebSecurity in the above example lets Spring ignore `/resources/**` and `/publics/**`. Therefore the `.antMatchers("/publics/**").hasRole("USER")` in HttpSecurity is *unconsidered*.

> This will omit the request pattern from the security filter chain entirely. 
>   Note that anything matching this path will then have no authentication or authorization services applied and will be freely accessible.

`configure(HttpSecurity)` allows configuration of web-based security at a *resource level*, based on a selection match - e.g. The example below restricts the URLs that start with `/admin/` to users that have *ADMIN role*, and declares that any other URLs need to be *successfully authenticated.*

`configure(WebSecurity)` is used for configuration settings that *impact global security* (ignore resources, set debug mode, reject requests by implementing a custom firewall definition). For example, the following method would cause any request that starts with `/resources/` to be *ignored for authentication* purposes.

```
AuthenticationManagerBuilder
extends AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder<AuthenticationManager,AuthenticationManagerBuilder>
implements ProviderManagerBuilder<AuthenticationManagerBuilder>
```

SecurityBuilder used to create an `AuthenticationManager`. Allows for easily building in *memory authentication, LDAP authentication, JDBC based authentication, adding UserDetailsService, and adding AuthenticationProvider's*.

```
@Override
     protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER"); 
        auth.userDetailsService(customUserDetailService).passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
     }
```

Comment: great answer. I am wondering if we ever need to call permitAll on HttpSecurity? Can't we just ignore all open url's like /register or /login using WebSecurity? Then why does all tutorials or answers use HttpSecurity.permitAll for /register and /login but WebSecurity.ingore for /publics of /resources ?