# Spring Security disable security for requests made FROM a certain url

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security

my application uses spring security. I know you can use antMatchers to permit requests for some URI that are mapped into your application. But I need too allow requests made from an external api to a URI in my application and just for that api. I need something like this:

```
     @Override
     protected void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception 
     {            
        web.ignoring()
          .antMatchers("http://externalTestApi.com");
     }
```

Does anybody know if this is possible? I did not find anything on this.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this (if you want to combine multiple conditions)

```
.authorizeRequests()
.antMatchers("/user/list")
.access("authenticated or hasIpAddress('666.666.666.666') or hasIpAddress('127.0.0.1') or hasIpAddress('0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1')")
```

or

```
.authorizeRequests()
.antMatchers("/user/list")
.hasIpAddress("0.0.0.0/0");
```

Comment: that works for the configure method that accepts a HttpSecurity as parameter, I need this for configure method with WebSecurity.

Comment: Aren't you extending `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`? Just @override `configure(HttpSecurity http)` and do your security there?

Comment: in WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter there are 2 configure methods, one that takes a HttpSecurity and one that takes WebSecurity, I need this for the one with WebSecurity because that is were the request is filtered and I get a 403 null. I am making a post from the api using RestTemplate and beacuse it is post it does some filtering and has a problem with my session.

Comment: If you move it to the method with HttpSecurity then security will be done in that layer.. I don't see any reason that prevents you to move your code to HttpSecurity.. see the differences here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22998731/httpsecurity-websecurity-and-authenticationmanagerbuilder

Comment: The two configuration methods have different purposes, as it is said in the link you posted, with WebSecurity you can reject requests, the security configuration is in such a way made that the request is rejected by some filters, if my I do what you suggested, my request will be rejected before it reaches any config that I make on HttpSecurity.

Comment: I need a way to tell spring security to not reject my request if it is coming from a certain URL.