# Spring Security permitall denies access when sending authorization header

Tags: spring-security

My security configuration is as follows:

```
http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/authenticate").fullyAuthenticated().anyRequest().permitAll().and().httpBasic();
```

It works and all the endpoints but `/authenticate` are not secured. But when the client sends `Authorization` header to any of the unsecured endpoints then Spring Security returns `401`.

```
curl -s -u asdf:asdf http://127.0.0.1:22000/info
{"timestamp":1511348485989,"status":401,"error":"Unauthorized","message":"Bad credentials","path":"/info"}
```

How I must to configure security to ignore `Authorization` header on unsecured endpoints **if it is sent**?

Thanks in advance

Comment: AFAIK it is not possible.

Comment: The basic authentication filter doesn't know that the URl is allowed for anonymous users,  so it can not handle this case. It just try to authenticate the user with username and password given in request.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HttpSecurity, WebSecurity and AuthenticationManagerBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22998731/httpsecurity-websecurity-and-authenticationmanagerbuilder)

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem by creating WebSecurityCustomizer bean SecurityConfiguration which configures to ignore required patterns:

```java
    @Bean
    public WebSecurityCustomizer webSecurityCustomizer() {
        return webSecurity -> webSecurity.ignoring().requestMatchers("/api/allowedPath/**");
    }
```