# Springboot webflux throwing 401 when Authorization header sent to unrestricted endpoint

Tags: spring-security, jwt, spring-security-oauth2

How to exclude `JwtTimestampValidator` from the spring security filter.
`JwtTimestampValidator` is getting executed when we pass a JWT token to an open or unrestricted endpoint.

```
http.authorizeExchange()
.pathMatchers("/open/**").permitAll()
.anyExchange().authenticated()
.and().oauth2ResourceServer().jwt();
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Boot 2: Basic Http Auth causes unprotected endpoints to respond with 401 "Unauthorized" if Authorization header is attached](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51496100/spring-boot-2-basic-http-auth-causes-unprotected-endpoints-to-respond-with-401)

Comment: The above solution doesn't work with spring webflux.
According to what I understand we use WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter for spring-web security configuration.