# SpringBoot Webflux - How to ignore requests with empty authorization headers

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-webflux

I am currently using a rather simple approach to restrict a certain suburl (everything under /api/rest) and all of its subpaths via WebFluxSecurity. Some paths (everything directly under the root NOT in /api/rest) are excluded so that they can be access without authorization. However, sometimes the accessing party might send an empty authorization header which leads to unsecured endpoints returning a 401.

See the relevant code here:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Value(value = "${...}")
    private String user;
    @Value(value = "${...}")
    private String pw;

    @Bean
    public MapReactiveUserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        PasswordEncoder encoder = PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();

        UserDetails user = User
                .withUsername(user)
                .password(encoder.encode(pw))
                .roles("USER")
                .build();

        return new MapReactiveUserDetailsService(user);
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        http
                .authorizeExchange(exchanges -> exchanges
                        .pathMatchers("/api/rest/**")
                        .authenticated()
                        .anyExchange()
                        .permitAll()
                )
                .httpBasic(withDefaults());
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

On stackoverflow I've only found a few suggestions how to handle this with WebSecurity. However, this is not possible for me as I use webflux security.

See e.g.

[Springboot webflux throwing 401 when Authorization header sent to unrestricted endpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71944045/springboot-webflux-throwing-401-when-authorization-header-sent-to-unrestricted-e)

[Spring Boot 2: Basic Http Auth causes unprotected endpoints to respond with 401 "Unauthorized" if Authorization header is attached](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51496100/spring-boot-2-basic-http-auth-causes-unprotected-endpoints-to-respond-with-401)

Comment: You mention passing an empty `Authorization` header. I cannot reproduce the behavior you're describing, and reviewing the code for `ServerHttpBasicAuthenticationConverter` which reads the header, it does not appear like an empty header value would cause a 401. Can you provide a sample request that reproduces this issue?

Comment: Maybe easier to replicate: it is not just an empty auth header that creates a 401. Even calling the endpoints that should match with `.anyExchange().permitAll()` (so unprotected endpoints) with wrong authentication (wrong password e.g) results in a 401. As far as I understand this is the case because of the `.authorizeExchange` that performs a match against the ReactiveUserDetails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR**

> *If you pass invalid credentials to any endpoint with `httpBasic()` enabled, it will return a 401 response.*

One important distinction that's relevant here is the difference between authentication and authorization. The `httpBasic()` DSL method adds the `AuthenticationWebFilter` configured for HTTP Basic. The `authorizeExchange(...)` DSL method defines authorization rules, such as `authenticated()` and `permitAll()`.

The authentication filter **appears earlier** in the Spring Security filter chain than the authorization filter, and so authentication **happens first** which we would expect. Based on your comments, it seems you are expecting authentication *not to happen* if you mark an endpoint as `permitAll()`, but this is not the case.

Whether authentication is actually attempted against a particular request depends on how the authentication filter matches the request. In the case of `AuthenticationWebFilter`, a `ServerWebExchangeMatcher` (`requiresAuthenticationMatcher`) determines whether authentication is required. For `httpBasic()`, every request requires authentication. *If you pass invalid credentials to any endpoint with `httpBasic()` enabled, it will return a 401 response.*

Additionally, a `ServerAuthenticationConverter` (`authenticationConverter`) is used to read the `Authorization` header and parse the credentials. This is what would fail if an invalid token (or `Authorization` header) is given. `ServerHttpBasicAuthenticationConverter` is used for `httpBasic()` and is fairly forgiving of invalid header values. I don't find any scenarios that fail and produce a 401 response except invalid credentials.