# Spring Boot 2 not ignoring authorization header on permitAll

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I've spring security configured like this:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Order(1)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
      .antMatchers("/rest/app/health").permitAll()
      .antMatchers("/*/app/**").authenticated()
      .antMatchers("/**").permitAll().and().httpBasic();
  }

  @Override
  public final void configure(final WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    super.configure(web);
    web.httpFirewall(new DefaultHttpFirewall());
  }

}
```

I've only included spring security and not oauth2. Due to some reason if someone is accessing any permitted url for eg. /rest/app/health with **Authorization** header he is getting **401 Unauthorized**. It's working fine without the header.

How can I ignore the Authorization header, because I need this header as a request param to delegate my request to a third party service.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47433314/spring-security-permitall-denies-access-when-sending-authorization-header

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Boot 2: Basic Http Auth causes unprotected endpoints to respond with 401 "Unauthorized" if Authorization header is attached](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51496100/spring-boot-2-basic-http-auth-causes-unprotected-endpoints-to-respond-with-401)

Answer (score 0):

Filters will be executed for all the endpoints that are configured through HttpSecurity. If you do not want filters to be applied for certain endpoints, include them in a method that configures WebSecurity.

You need to change this method

```
 @Override
  public final void configure(final WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    super.configure(web);
    web.httpFirewall(new DefaultHttpFirewall());
  }
```

to:

```
@Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) {
        web.ignoring()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/rest/app/health");
    }
```