# Unable to load static content in spring security

Tags: javascript, java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have built a basic spring authentication service from this source:
https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/

Tried to include JS files from Local folders using almost all solutions on stackoverflow but I couldn't. When the html page loads, it says:
"Uncaught ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined"

Here is my home.html script:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3">
    <head>
        <title>Spring Security Example</title>
        <script type="javascript" src="test.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body onload="myFunction()">
        <h1>Welcome!</h1>

        <p>Click <a href="/hello">here</a> to see a greeting.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is where my js file is located and htmls are placed in templates folder.

[image]

here is my mvcConfig code:

```
package hello;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewControllerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;


@Configuration
public class MvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/home").setViewName("home");
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("home");
        registry.addViewController("/hello").setViewName("redirect:http://localhost:3000/home.html");
        registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    if (!registry.hasMappingForPattern("/webjars/**")) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**").addResourceLocations(
                "classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
    }
    if (!registry.hasMappingForPattern("/**")) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/", "classpath:/resources/","classpath:/static/", "classpath:/public/");
    }

    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
        .addResourceLocations("/resources/");


}

}
```

WebSecurityConfig code:

```
package hello;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.provisioning.InMemoryUserDetailsManager;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/home","/resources/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout()
                .permitAll();
    }

@Bean
@Override
public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
    UserDetails user =
         User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
            .username("user")
            .password("password")
            .roles("USER")
            .build();

    return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user);
}
```

}

Comment: the src of test.js is not just test.js if the file is in a different folder. Changing the path to `src="../test.js"` might be the answer already.

Comment: I tried this but didn't worked..

Comment: when I open the html in chrome directly, its loading the js file normally.
but when that html is invoked from the application, its throwing this error

Answer (score 1):

Whatever the folder are in src/main/resources ,you can configure them like this ,Create this method in your security config class,generally we put static resources in static folder inside src/main/resources.

```
//this method allows static resources to be neglected by spring security
        @Override
        public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
            web
                .ignoring()
                .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/static/**", "/css/**", "/js/**", "/images/**","/assets/**","/fonts/**","/dis/**","/vendor1/**");
        }
```

Comment: You should use websecurity not httpsecurity ,this solution will work  for sure-for more you can see this answer -https://stackoverflow.com/a/28272347/7849549

Comment: changed my script path to :
<script type="javascript" src="resources/static/test.js"></script>

and changed my WebSecurityConfig too but its not working

Comment: @AjayKarri create a static folder in src/main/resource put all your css there ,by default it looks for static folder ,so if you have static/js/style.js you can just write <script type="javascript" src=" /js/style.js"></script>  also tru removing slash before -js

Comment: <script type="javascript" src=" js/style.js"></script>  or  <script type="javascript" src="/js/style.js"></script>

Comment: Thank you for your time and solution.
I tried mixing up your both solutions and made some more changes.
then it worked :)

Comment: I am in a confused state to accept one of these answers. give me sometime i'll do some changes and check whose solution fits better to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

In the `WebSecurityConfig` class you set permitAll to only `'/'`, `'/home'`, and `'/resources/**'`. An anonymous user can access these three endpoints without security check.

For `test.js` file, the src points to `test.js` in the current url. So when you run it on localhost, the browser tries to find the `test.js` as `http://localhost:{port}/{current-page-url}/test.js`

For example, if the page is under `/home` then the browser calls `http://localhost:8080/home/test.js`, but as you defined in the `WebSecurityConfig` any call except `/home` itself will be blocked by Spring Security. (`/home` is not the same as `/home/**`)

So what you need to do is to change the src url to `<script src="/resources/test.js"></script>` Because anything under the `/resources/**` endpoint can be accessed by anyone and it is already registered in the resourceHandler configuration in the `MvcConfig`

```
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
    .addResourceLocations("classpath:/");
```

Hope this helps! Happy Coding :)

**ADD :**

Also the in the `<script>` tag you should change the `type` attribute to `text/javascript` or you can just remove the attribute and it will work.

Comment: I already tried this solution but it didn't worked..
let me try again and confirm

Comment: don't forget to add `/` at the beginning to point to the classpath

Comment: Not working.. it says :
<html><body><h1>Whitelabel Error Page</h1><p>This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.</p><div id='created'>Fri Sep 28 12:58:49 IST 2018</div><div>There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).</div><div>An error happened during template parsing (template: &quot;class path resource [templates/home.html]&quot; - line 5, col 3)</div></body></html>

Comment: Ajay if the `test.js` file is in the resources folder then you should point the resourceLocation as `.addResourceLocations("classpath:/")` or as Jai mentioned you can put all static files in the /resources/static folder to organize them and `.addResourceLocations("classpath:/static")`

Comment: Thank you koo..
updating this has solved half of my issue.
 registry.addResourceHandler("/**") .addResourceLocations("classpath:/");

Comment: Good. Now it seems the `test.js` is loaded but `myFunction()` is not found right? What you can do is to change the type to `<script type="text/javascript" src=...` or you can just remove the type