# Spring security don't allow resources and after login browser shows only a css file?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception{
    httpSecurity
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/resources").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
    .formLogin()
        .loginPage("/login")
        .defaultSuccessUrl("/myList")
        .permitAll()
        .and()
    .logout()
        .permitAll();
}
```

I try to make a custom login page to the Spring security but after hours and hours still, have the same problem. The whole project is made with java and HTML/CSS. Thanks for the help!

Comment: What do you mean by 'shows only a css file'? Does the CSS file content get displayed in the browser? What do you see in the browser's development tool network tab?

Answer (score 1):

To ignore resources you should use WebSecurity not HttpSecurity

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
  web
    .ignoring()
    .antMatchers("/resources/**");
}
```

For more explanation see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22998731/httpsecurity-websecurity-and-authenticationmanagerbuilder)