# Ignore authorization for some endpoints in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, oauth

I have my OAuth server and client which is  being authorized by Oauth2.

Now if I need to call my service I need to:

1. Generate access token from the server using below API :

   `localhost:9191/oauth/token?grant_type=password&username=krish&password=kpass`

   Which is giving response like :

   ```
   "access_token": "ee41435d-8ad9-432e-82c1-07477e2b6956",
   "token_type": "bearer",
   "refresh_token": "ea6d83b4-62f6-4eaf-9f89-8600bd36690d",
   "expires_in": 3429,
   "scope": "READ WRITE"
   ```
2. Now I am passing access token, to run the client service like below:

[image]

So this is manually I am doing it. But I need to run it from the client code. When I am trying to hit the first API itself (server) to get the token, it is saying unauthorized.
My service code is below :
[image]

I need to skip the authentication from the `/getToken` controller. How can I do that? Can anyone please help

My WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter class is as below:
I added highlighted code after reading one answer below, but that also not working.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to create a new configuration extending the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter and override the configure method.
Have a look at this [guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/) for a practical example.
Want you want to focus on is this part

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/home").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout()
                .permitAll();
    }
}
```

As you can see in the example the path "/login","/","/home" are excluded from authentication.
Check this other answer also: [Spring Security exclude url patterns in security annotation configurartion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22767205/spring-security-exclude-url-patterns-in-security-annotation-configurartion)

Comment: I need to add in Client or Server ? @berrur

Comment: In the server, this is a Spring configuration. Just create a new class and use the annotation `@Configuration` and Spring will handle it. I'm assuming you are using Spring since this you tagged this answer with Spring Boot and Spring Security.

Comment: Yes I added the config as you said, but that also not working.. Its then also authenticating (/getName) request. I have added screenshot in the question. Please check @berrur

Comment: Try to override the `configure(WebSecurity web)` and use `web.ignoring().antMatchers("/getToken")`

Comment: Also check [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22998731/httpsecurity-websecurity-and-authenticationmanagerbuilder) for further understanding on how to manipulate Spring Security behaviour

Comment: Thanks it worked with web.ignoring().antMatchers("/getToken") { I added in client code}