# Unable to set a Spring webflux endpoint into the white list defined in Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have a Spring webflux endpoint definition like this:

```
@RouterOperations({
    @RouterOperation(
            method = RequestMethod.GET,
            path = "/ping",
            produces = {MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE},
            operation = @Operation(operationId = "ping")

    ),
    @RouterOperation(
            method = RequestMethod.POST,
            path = "/pong",
            produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE},
            operation = @Operation(operationId = "pong", parameters = {
                        @Parameter(in = ParameterIn.PATH, name = "param", description = "method", required = true)
                }
            )

    ),
    @RouterOperation(
            method = RequestMethod.GET,
            path = "/kick",
            operation = @Operation(operationId = "kick", parameters = {
                    @Parameter(in = ParameterIn.PATH, name = "id", description = "kick", required = true)
            })
    )
})
@Bean
RouterFunction<ServerResponse> routes() {
    return route()
            .GET("/ping", pingRequestHandler::ping)
            .POST("/pong", pongRequestHandler::pong)
            .GET("/kick", kickRequestHandler::kick)
            .build();
}
```

I have the following spring security definition:

public class SecurityConfig {

```
@Bean
public ReactiveAuthenticationManager authenticationManager(final MyAuthenticationProvider myAuthenticationProvider) {
    return new ReactiveAuthenticationManagerAdapter(myAuthenticationProvider);
}

@Bean
public SecurityWebFilterChain securityWebFilterChain(final ServerHttpSecurity httpSecurity,
                                                     final ReactiveAuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
    httpSecurity.csrf(ServerHttpSecurity.CsrfSpec::disable)
            .formLogin(ServerHttpSecurity.FormLoginSpec::disable)
            .logout(ServerHttpSecurity.LogoutSpec::disable)
            .requestCache(ServerHttpSecurity.RequestCacheSpec::disable);


    httpSecurity.authorizeExchange(auth -> auth.pathMatchers( "/favicon.ico",
                                                              "/v3/api-docs",
                                                              "/v3/api-docs/**",
                                                              "/api/docs/**",
                                                              "/configuration/ui",
                                                              "/configuration/security",
                                                              "/swagger-ui/**",
                                                              "/swagger-resources",
                                                              "/swagger-resources/**",
                                                              "/swagger-ui.html",
                                                              "/webjars/**",
                                                              "/webjars/swagger-ui/**",
                                                              "/swagger-doc/**",
                                                              "/actuator/**",
                                                              "/ping")   <----- Added to white list
                    .permitAll()
                    .anyExchange().authenticated()
                )
            .httpBasic(httpBasic -> httpBasic.authenticationManager(authenticationManager));

    return httpSecurity.build();
}
```

}

I added the /ping endpoint to the white list and I expect it can be run without username/passwork being passed.

However, It doesn't work if I do not pass any authentication info. All other endpoins in the white list works fine without authentication.

The /ping endpoint also works if I just pass my username, not a password. But it won't work if I completely turn off authentication (i.e. no Authentication header sent in the HTTP header).

What could be the problem?

Comment: check this link [spring security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22998731/httpsecurity-websecurity-and-authenticationmanagerbuilder)

Answer (score 0):

Reorder your security rules

Replace

```
                "/actuator/**",
                "/ping"
                ).permitAll()
                .anyExchange().authenticated()
```

with

```
                "/actuator/**"
                ).permitAll()
                .pathMatchers("/ping").permitAll()
                .anyExchange().authenticated()
```