# Disable authentication for curl on a specific uri in spring-boot running

Tags: java, authentication, curl, spring-boot

I'm trying to diable authentication for a specific uri in my application, running the following curl command:

```
curl --header "content-type: application/soap+xml" -d @src/test/resources/xml-file https://localhost:5434/ws  --insecure
```

At the moment it only works with:

```
curl -u *****:***** --header "content-type: application/soap+xml" -d @src/test/resources/xml-fike https://localhost:5434/ws  --insecure
```

Here is my updated confifure method:

```
@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
    http.anonymous()
            .and()
            .antMatcher("/ws");

    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/rest").access("hasRole('USER', 'ADMIN')")
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated();
    System.out.println("applying anomyous to ws, and auth for rest");
}
```

This solution is based on the similar post I have found on stack so far, although when i run the desired curl command, I don't get any output. I still need authentication for my "/rest" uri. User credentials are initialized in the following way:

```
@Configuration
public class AuthenticationConfiguration extends GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter {

    // overides deafult password, here you can add additional users
    @Override
    public void init(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("*******").password("*****").roles("USER")
                .and()
                .withUser("*******").password("******").roles("USER", "ADMIN");
        System.out.println("global configurer finished");
    }

}
```

Some of the posts i have looked at: 
[How to disable spring security for particular url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30366405/how-to-disable-spring-security-for-particular-url)
[Spring Security exclude url patterns in security annotation configurartion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22767205/spring-security-exclude-url-patterns-in-security-annotation-configurartion)

I updated configure method with, but still not getting the desired output.

```
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        http.
                .antMatchers("/ws")
                .permitAll()
                .anonymous();
}
```

So I'm trying add this method, but it requires additional methods. But I don't know what to add.

Comment: `permitAll` still requires an authentication and as you haven't enabled anonymous authentication the result is you need to authenticate always.

Comment: I've changed it to anonymous, but it still doesn't work

Comment: You haven't changed anything. You only added `anonymous` and removed the `permitAll`. You need to keep that.

Comment: I updated my configure method with permitAll but i cant get the method to work